# Time Recorder Using Ionic 4 + angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I'm creating a time recorder using ionic 4, I added an ng plugin called circle progress. When my circle reach 100 % which is equal to the time set, I want the display time counter to stop.

**The typescript codes:**

Reset Duration

```
   <circle-progress (click)="startTime()" [percent]="percent" [radius]="radius" [maxPercent]="100" [showTitle]="false"
     [showSubtitle]="false" [showUnits]="false" [outerStrokeWidth]="16" [outerStrokeColor]="'#8000FF'"
     [showZeroOuterStroke]="false" [backgroundStroke]="'#33003F'" [backgroundStrokeWidth]="3"
     [outerStrokeGradient]="true" [outerStrokeGradientStopColor]="'#FF00CB'" [showInnerStroke]="false">
   </circle-progress>

   <p>{{ elapsed.h }}: {{ elapsed.m}}: {{ elapsed.s}}</p>

   <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
     <ng-container *ngIf="timer == false; else running">
       <ion-fab-button (click)="startTime()">
         <ion-icon name="play"></ion-icon>
       </ion-fab-button>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-template #running>
       <ion-fab-button (click)="stopTime()">
         <ion-icon name="square"></ion-icon>
       </ion-fab-button>
     </ng-template>
   </ion-fab>

 </ion-content>
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: please show the code that you are using to progress `elapsed`. Is it part of a library?

Comment: no, sir... i'm getting error trying to post to stackoverflow

Comment: you don't show enough to answer at the moment, your timer library should have some kind of update function which you can use to update the `circle-progress` and stop when it reaches a certain amount.